# Can I set up Cascade deleting in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I know this is probably on the Internet somewhere but I can't find the answer here on Stackoverflow so I thought I may boost up the knowledge base here a little.

I'm a newbie to Ruby and Rails but my company is getting pretty invested in it so I'm trying to get to know it in a little more detail.

It's been difficult for me to change my mindset to designing an application from the "model" rather the from the database, so I'm trying to figure out how would do all of the design work that I have classically done in the Database in the Rails model instead.

So the most recent task that I have given myself is to figure out how to configure a Rails database model to do cascading deletes? Is there an easy way of doing this? Or would I have to go into the MySql and set this up?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

you can also set the :dependent option to :delete_all. :delete_all will issue a single SQL statement to delete all child records. because of this using :delete_all may give you better performance.

```
has_many :memberships, dependent: :delete_all
```

Comment: Your explanation is confusing. A single SQL statement will be used, but the destroy method will not be called for each child row. You have to use destroy_all for that.

Comment: @John - hope the edits clear up the confusion. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between using `:delete_all` and `:destroy` for this. Both will cause child memberships (1 level for delete [citation needed] and `n` for destroy (if their children have dependent destroys)) to be removed from the database, but `:destroy` will instantiate each child object and run any callbacks first, whereas `:delete_all` will directly run a SQL DELETE statement in the database. `:destroy` is slower because of that, but it allows you to have callbacks when a record is destroyed. Circumventing Rails on one end and potential n^x instantiation on the other.

Comment: I suggest also setting up database foreign keys. That way records are deleted with one operation. See the below answer I posted.

Comment: I think it's better to use the usual `dependent: :destroy`, otherwise you'll skip callbacks on the child model - also as a good rule of thumb, imho is better to avoid premature optimizations.

Answer (score 72):

Yeah you can, if you are using a relationship like has_many you just do this

```
has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Dan,

So I guess my next question is if I run a db migrate command will that actually set that up in the db? Or is the cascading completely handled by rails?

Comment: Yes, it's handled by rails. (Do make sure you really always need to delete every related rows, though.)

Comment: @Matt - the has_many line should be in your model class, the migration won't add that for you.

Comment: I prefer this solution because it also works if the dependent model has another has_many relation

Answer (score 35):

Contrary to the provided answer I highly suggest also doing this on a database level. In case you have different processes or a multi threaded environment it could happen that records are not properly deleted. Furthermore the database foreign key makes things way faster when deleting lots of data.

Like in the suggested answer do this:

```
has_many :memberships, dependent: :delete_all
```

However also make sure to setup a `foreign_key` in a migration. That way the database takes care of deleting the records automatically for you.

To nullify the values when a membership is deleted, assuming you have a user model:

```
add_foreign_key :users, :memberships, on_delete: :nullify
```

You can also delete all the models whenever a membership is deleted

```
add_foreign_key :users, :memberships, on_delete: :cascade
```

Comment: So can I use both "has_many :memberships, dependent: :delete_all" and "add_foreign_key :users, :memberships, on_delete: :cascade" ? Will it work well?

Comment: You won't even need to setup the `delete_all` in the model. The foreign key will take care of deleting everything properly for you on a database level.

Comment: I'm curious about what happens when you do both. Seems like it shouldn't have a negative effect but has anyone had a bad experience with this practice of doing both AR and DB level?

Comment: Database level is what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. The others seem like they only work if my queries stick to standard ActiveRecord operations.

Answer (score 10):

Just keep in mind that delete_all will not execute any callbacks (like before_destroy and after_destroy) on the child records.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this plugin might give you what you're looking for if you want the cascading deletes reflected in the actual database structure:

http://www.redhillonrails.org/foreign_key_migrations.html

Format for using this in a migration would be something like this:

```
create_table :orders do |t|
  t.column :customer_id, :integer, :on_delete => :set_null, :on_update => :cascade
  ...
end
```

Comment: That link is dead but this is a newer alternative:
http://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner