# How can I delete child objects when the parent is deleted in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, cascade

model a:

```
has_many :b, :dependent => :delete_all
```

model b:

```
belongs_to :a
belongs_to :c
```

model c:

```
has_many :b
```

When I delete an `a`, I would also like to have children `b's` deleted so that they get removed from any `c's` that may reference them. However, the above isn't working. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331394/can-i-set-up-cascade-deleting-in-rails

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Like so:

```
class Widgets < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :whatevers, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**Update**

Your recent comment indicates you are using the delete() method to delete your objects. This will not use the callbacks. Please read [the manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002331) for specifics.

Comment: I can't figure out why this isn't working. When I delete an 'a' that references a 'b', and that 'b' is also referenced in a 'c', the 'b' is still a child of the 'c' after deletion of 'a', using the above.

Comment: James, you'd have to have :dependent => :destroy for all of the objects in the chain.

Comment: hmmm... works when I call destroy on the parent, but doesn't work when I call delete. Is this expected?

Comment: @James: Yes this is expected. Delete doesn't use the :dependent callbacks. See: http://www.nickpeters.net/2007/12/21/delete-vs-destroy/

Comment: @james, to be ridiculously clear, `has_many :b, :dependent => :delete_all` will remove all of a's children if you call `a.destroy`.