# Can you nullify the foreign key on a has_many, belongs_to with multiple foreign keys during the dependent: :nullify callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a User class like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end
```

and a Payment class like this:

```rb
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'seller_id'
end
```

When I destroy a user I would like the foreign key in the Payment to be nil so I add a `dependent: :nullify` callback to the User model like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments, foreign_key: "seller_id", class_name: 'Payment', dependent: :nullify
end
```

sure enough my spec passes:

```rb
seller.destroy
expect(payment.reload.seller).to be_nil # => true
```

I would like the buyer_id in the Payment to also be nil when the user is destroyed so I add another `dependent: :nullify` callback to the User model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments, foreign_key: "buyer_id", class_name: 'Payment', dependent: :nullify
  has_many :payments, foreign_key: "seller_id", class_name: 'Payment', dependent: :nullify
end
```

but then my spec fails:

```rb
buyer.destroy
expect(payment.reload.buyer).to be_nil
```

I get this error: `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table “xxx” violates foreign key constraint`

I noticed that whichever of these two  `has_many` associations is defined last in the model is the one that passes and whichever `has_many` is defined first fails.

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38655056/4369077) I got both tests to pass by making a migration so that the foreign keys are nullified on the database level instead of relying on callbacks.

```rb
def change
    remove_foreign_key :payments, :users, column: :buyer_id
    add_foreign_key :payments, :users, column: :buyer_id, on_delete: :nullify

    remove_foreign_key :payments, :users, column: :seller_id
    add_foreign_key :payments, :users, column: :seller_id, on_delete: :nullify
  end
```